# Is articleId of a Journal Article same as the entryId?

Tags: liferay-6, article

Is the articleId of a Journal Article same as the entryId we get from:

```
assetEntry.getEntryId();
```

?
If not how can i get articleId?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get the problem here,
you can use `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil` to get the JournalArticles by various get Methods.  After this you can just use `JournalArticle.getArticleId()`